# CKEditor : add columns supports

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor5. I'm looking for a plugin to extend its functionalities to manage columns (not `<table>`, but `div` or whatever suitable element for layout purpose). I just can't find anything like that.

Any idea to achieve that? Should I implement my own plugin to do that?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?